# My react project isn't displaying anything even though I have my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, nodemon, node-mongodb-native

#### Title: React Webpage with MongoDB Not Displaying LoginPage

**Question:**

I'm working on a React project that uses MongoDB for data storage and Nodemon to run the server. My current issue is with the navigation bar; it's supposed to display the LoginPage when the server is up, but it's not appearing. Despite creating dummy data and checking the DOM, I can't pinpoint the problem. Below are the relevant code snippets:

**App.js:**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './Scene/homePage';
import LoginPage from './Scene/loginPage';
import ProfilePage from './Scene/profilePage';
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { themeSettings } from './theme';

function App() {
  const mode = useSelector((state) => state.mode);
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/profile/:userId" element={<ProfilePage />} />
          </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**LoginPage Index.jsx:**

```
import { Box, Typography, useTheme, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import Form from "./form";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isNonMobileScreens = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1000px)");
  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        width="100%"
        backgroundColor={theme.palette.background.alt}
        p="1rem 6%"
        textAlign="center"
      >
        <Typography fontWeight="bold" fontSize="32px" color="primary">
          Sociopedia
        </Typography>
      </Box>

      <Box
        width={isNonMobileScreens ? "50%" : "93%"}
        p="2rem"
        m="2rem auto"
        borderRadius="1.5rem"
        backgroundColor={theme.palette.background.alt}
      >
        <Typography fontWeight="500" variant="h5" sx={{ mb: "1.5rem" }}>
          Welcome to Blogit! Reinventing Blogging with style!
        </Typography>
        <Form />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

**HomePage.jsx:**

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Navbar from "Scene/navbar"; 

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Navbar />
        </Box>
    );   
};

export default HomePage;
```

**Error Messages from Inspect Element > Sources:**

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
...
```

I've debugged and checked that all paths are correct, yet the LoginPage won't display. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

**Tags:** `javascript`, `reactjs`, `mongodb`, `nodemon`, `mui`

Comment: Are you using Vite or CRA or Rewired or ... ?

Comment: @GregFenton Im using mongodb

Comment: No, I mean how did you create your React project?  That typically is the "development system" that you would be running your React project with when in development (and using to `build` your app when you are ready to deploy it).

Comment: @GregFenton I used node.js using npm.
 React Router for navigation, Material-UI for UI components.

Comment: @GregFenton

here is the github repo:
https://github.com/Anish-I/tempsocmedia

Comment: clear  your browser cache

Comment: It uses `react-scripts` (see the package.json file).  So that means you are using a project that was generated by Create-React-App (CRA).

Comment: @AdesojiAlu I did that, infact I used a different browser entirely, but same result

Comment: Yikes...you committed your `node_modules` directory at your project root.  You almost certainly don't want that checked into your git repository.

Comment: @GregFenton I see, im new to react, and I was following a tutorial to setup. But I tried running my code, yet not working

Comment: @GregFenton oh shoot, thought I ignored node_modules, let me update rq

Comment: @GregFenton just updated my github repo, let me know if you need anything else. Ive been stuck at this for a good 6 hours haha

Comment: I don't see any code in your project that loads `App.js` nor that renders it to the HTML's root div.  Something is very wrong with your React startup code.

Comment: @GregFenton what to do?

Comment: At this stage I'd suggest starting over. Create React App is no longer recommended anyway. Give [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) a try... `npm create vite@latest tempsocmedia -- --template react`

Comment: @Phil got it. Thank you

Comment: What @Phil said :)

Comment: Also, consider following a newer tutorial.  A lot has changed in these technologies over the years.  If you are just getting started, consider picking up a tutorial created in the past 12 months or so.  (I also would encourage you to avoid Redux as a starting point....I have actually gotten rid of Redux from all of my code bases and use cleaner/smaller/simpler/better tools now).